# Gets the total expenses per store in a Pivot Table and places them in a column

Tags: excel, vba

For context, I have a Pivot table that has contains store numbers, line item expenses for each store (number varies per week), and how much the expenses were.  The pivot table is already filtered based on two fields from my Pivot Table.

Store number Is always in column A.  The total of the value of all items for a particular store is always in Column E after the final line item.  The bottom of the pivot table contains the grand total of all stores.

I’m trying to create a VBA script that scans through the Pivot table and takes each of the line item total for a store and puts them in their own column (e.g. Starts in Column J2 then J3, J4, …).

```vb
Sub GetAndConcatenateStoreNetAmount()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim pfStore As PivotField
    Dim pfAmount As PivotField
    Dim piStore As PivotItem
    Dim totalText As String
    Dim targetCell As Range
    Dim cellRow As Long
    
    ' Set the worksheet containing the pivot table
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 
    
    ' Set the pivot table object
    Set pt = ws.PivotTables("PivotTable1") 
    
    ' Set the pivot fields for Store Number and Line Item Net Amount
    Set pfStore = pt.PivotFields("Store Number") 
    Set pfAmount = pt.PivotFields("Line Item Net Amount") 
    
    ' Define the target cell where totals will be placed
    Set targetCell = ws.Cells(2, 9) ' Column J, Row 2
    
    ' Initialize the totalText string
    totalText = ""
    
    ' Loop through the pivot field items to get store totals
    cellRow = targetCell.Row
    For Each piStore In pfStore.PivotItems
        ' Check if the pivot item is not a subtotal
        If piStore.Position > 1 Then
            ' Get the sum of Line Item Net Amount for the current store
            Dim totalAmount As Double

            **totalAmount = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(pfStore.DataRange, piStore.Name, pfAmount.DataRange)**
            
            ' Concatenate the store total to the totalText string
            totalText = totalText & piStore.Name & ": " & totalAmount & vbCrLf

        End If
    Next piStore
    
    ' Write the concatenated store totals to the target cell
    targetCell.Value = totalText

 ‘ Move one cell down for the next value
    targetCell.Value = pi.Name
    Set target Cell = targetCell.Offset(1,9) ‘ Next cell in Column J
    
    ' Clean up
    Set ws = Nothing
    Set pt = Nothing
    Set pfStore = Nothing
    Set pfAmount = Nothing
End Sub
```

When I try to run my VBA code, I get Run-time error '1004" unable to get the datarange property of the PivotField class. I tried adding .select to the end of pfAmount.DataRange, but it still didn't work. Am I headed in the right direction with my VBA and is there a better way to implement this?  Let me know if you need more info.  I bolded the line which is causing the error.

Comment: Please show your pivottable layout.

Answer (score 0):

`PivotItem` doesn't have `DataRange` property. You can use `GetPivotData` to extract data from pivottable.

```vb
    For Each piStore In pfStore.PivotItems
        ' Check if the pivot item is not a subtotal
        If piStore.Position > 1 Then
            ' Get the sum of Line Item Net Amount for the current store
            Dim totalAmount As Double
            ' totalAmount = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(pfStore.DataRange, piStore.Name, pfAmount.DataRange)
            totalAmount = pt.GetPivotData("Line Item Net Amount", pfStore.Name, piStore.Name)
            ' Concatenate the store total to the totalText string
            totalText = totalText & piStore.Name & ": " & totalAmount & vbCrLf
        End If
    Next piStore
```